# Plotly/Dash large dataset Densitymapbox memory usage

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataset with millions of Latitude/Longitude points that we are plotting at high resolution using `plotly-dash` with a `Densitymapbox`:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame()
# ...
go.Densitymapbox(
    lat=data['Latitude'],
    lon=data['Longitude'],
    z=data['Count'],
    hoverinfo='skip',
    # ...
)
```

According to Mapbox, their library should support millions of points without issue as shown by their demo @ https://demos.mapbox.com/100mpoints/

When I try to do this, it does appear that Mapbox is able to handle the requests. However in my implementation with plotly/dash, unlike the demo above, the browser gets underwater. The first load works fine (although does use a lot of memory), but on a reload of the data, Chrome crashes and Firefox reports an out of memory error to the console and does not update the heatmap.

The data set I am using is 1093737 points. Doing back-of-the-napkin math, this should only be < ~25 MB of data `(1093737 * (8 + 8 + 8))` for 2 double precision floating point values and 1 (64bit) integer, and the amount of data sent to the browser does show this. However, the browser process balloons in memory to over 3.5GB and then on subsequent reloads, it appears the browser runs out of memory.

Are there any facilities in dash/plotly to prevent this from taking down the browser? I do not need to interact with the points of density plot, and have set the `hoverinfo='skip'` to indicate that, but would like to keep the interactivity of the heatmap recalculating the overlay when the map zoom changes. I am investigating other alternatives such as rasterizing the heatmap server side using `datashader`, but that would remove this interactivity which I would like to keep.

Comment: Hi @clcto !  I'm running in the same problem. Did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3):

[LensPy](https://github.com/serant/lenspy) was created to solve this exact problem. It is built on top of Plotly Dash to allow you to plot very large datasets while maintaining fluid interactivity. Here is an example of how you can achieve this with a Mapbox.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from lenspy import DynamicPlot

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/earthquakes-23k.csv')
fig = px.density_mapbox(df,
                        lat='Latitude', lon='Longitude',
                        z='Magnitude',
                        radius=10,
                        center=dict(lat=0, lon=180),
                        zoom=0,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")

plot = DynamicPlot(fig)
plot.show()
```

Disclaimer: I am the creator of LensPy.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer look, but it didn't look like `Densitymapbox` was supported. Also, how would I use `DynamicPlot` in an existing dash app? Is this all client side or would I have to reload my data everytime the zoom changes?

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example with a Densitymapbox which is now officially supported. I also expanded on the docs here to show how you would use this in your own Dash app. https://lenspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-with-ploty-dash-applications

This follows a client <> server model. The reason why large graphs crash your browser is because you are rendering the entire css and html in your browser. A 32bit value will easily triple in size when it's rendered in browser due to the html/css that your graph is composed of.

Comment: Is there an R shiny equivalent of this?

Comment: This `lenspy` is peace of crap. Does nothing but downsampling and may cause trouble. Wasted My time :-(

Comment: I’m sorry to hear that this has been your experience. We are working on reviving and rearchitecting this project as there are more users and use cases that initially expected (this project is exceeding my expectations for how popular it would be). 

The best way to support is to report your feedback/issues to our GitHub. Thank you for trying it out and I hope we’ll be able to swing your opinion around. 

https://github.com/telemetrydb/lenspy/issues